# Generic way to allow drag and drop to an elevated process?

Tags: windows-7, elevation

On Windows 7 (and I think also Vista) an elevated process will not by default accept items dragged and dropped onto it. I have a few programs which I *have* to run elevated, which is nicely accomplished with SuRun. However, these processes won't accept dragging and dropping items on their windows from processes that aren't elevated.

How can I override this default behavior for given processes, based on the name of the process (path to its executable image etc)?

---

Just to make sure people get what I am up to. I am a developer myself and I *know* for a fact that [it's possible to filter and "unfilter" messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388202.aspx) (and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632675.aspx)) to an elevated program. So I am literally asking for some solution that provides this canned and doesn't require turning off UAC completely or start the "dragging program" elevated every time, which I don't deem an option.

Comment: @techie007: none of the answers in that alleged duplicate even touches the question I have raised.

Comment: It's still the same question and, IMO anyway, the accepted answer IS the actual answer (turn off UAC or proxy through another file manager that's running elevated).  If you'd like newer/better/different answers to the existing question, perhaps consider [placing a bounty](http://superuser.com/privileges/set-bounties) on it.